# Dolby Digital Sound Designer (In South Africa)

Tags: sound-design

I'm studying my honours degree this year and part of it is an internship, the joys of this is I get to choose who i intern under. My question is can anybody recommend me a brilliant Dolby digital sound designer who i can intern under and their website so that i can supply all their details to my institution

Comment: what do you mean by "dolby digital sound designer"? to my knowledge, dobly isn't in that game. they may provide certifications to STUDIOS using their equipment (though i don't really know about that), but i don't believe they certify individuals for anything besides repair.

Answer (score 1):

I teach in SD in South Africa and know a few people who are proficient in surround sound mixing and sound design. There are people here who claim they are but are not. You might want to contact Jim Petrak at www.soundsurfers.co.za or contact Waterfront Studio's in Cape Town. Both are good places but here, there are not many who truly understand what it is you are looking for.